# css3 transition without hover?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am following a CSS3 transition tutorial: [here](http://thecreativeservicesblog.com/2011/10/css3-animations-using-transition-tranform-and-keyframes/)

I cant manage to get this to work without having to hover. Does anyone have any idea how I could have this same effect from this tutorial without having to hover on the body?

Thanks

Comment: What action do you want to trigger the CSS transition with?  It has to be triggered by something.

Comment: thats what I figured, I was hoping it could start on its own, or page load, I just dont want to have to be hovering in the body for it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can trigger it upon page load, but you would have to do that by adding a class upon page load where the animation is set for the class.

Comment: A demo thanks to @jfriend00 http://jsfiddle.net/mALEC/1/

Comment: perfect thanks jfriend00 and @Rufus if you respond with an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the answer from @Rufus by simply putting the 'test' class on the body directly in the markup. There's no reason to add it with javascript later.

If you were using css3 transition, then you WOULD need to add the transitioned class after page load, but since you are using keyframe animation, you don't need to wait before adding it.

Here's the example from @Rufus modified to show what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/mALEC/2/